# Get Facebook page feed posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, feed, posts

I'm new to the fb graph api. Can someone please help me to find a way to retrieve the feed posts on a fan page wall, that I am the admin of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Curl Call to this URL:
`
https://graph.facebook.com/< YOUR_APP_ID >/feed?access_token=< ACCESS_TOKEN_OF_fb_APPLICATION 
>

Comment: Thanks.

Do you know why I can only see the posts in the feed object that is posted by the logged in user? I make posts programmaticaly and when I use the API Explorer I only see my posts and not the other users posts in the feed JSON object.